# ¿Como puedo mostrar una gráfica hecha con groupby en un html con WebBrowser?

Tags: html, python, pandas

```
import webbrowser
import pandas as pd
from statistics import *


data = pd.read_csv("fisica.csv")

vel = data["Velocidad"].unique()
print(vel)

# frecuancia absoluta
datafi = pd.crosstab(index=data["Velocidad"], columns = "Cantidad")

# frecuencia acumulada absoluta
datafi["acum"] = datafi["Cantidad"].cumsum()
print(datafi)
#fracuencia relativa
datafi["Relative"] = 100 * datafi["Cantidad"] / 29
#frecuencia acumulada relativa
datafi["acumr"] = datafi["Relative"].cumsum()
print(datafi)


def vg1():
    # grafica absoluta
    datafi.groupby('Velocidad')['Cantidad'].sum().plot(kind='bar',legend='Reverse')
    print (datafi)


def vg2():

    # grafica relativa
    datafi.groupby('Velocidad')['Relative'].sum().plot(kind='pie')
    print(datafi)


def vg3():

    # grafica de frecuencias acumuladas
    datafi.groupby('acumr')['acum'].sum().plot(kind='hist',legend='Reverse')


def vg4():
    # Poligono de frecuencias
    datafi.groupby('Velocidad')['Cantidad'].sum().plot(kind='line',legend = 'Reverse')
```

Answer (score 0):

No veo la manera de que `webbrowser` abra código directamente de un `str` o similar, por lo que será necesario guardarlo en un archivo previamente para abrirlo.

Dependiendo del uso que le vayas a dar te puede interesar:

- Guardar la imagen y un archivo html que la muestre.
- Guardar sólo un archivo html con la imagen codificada en el propio código.
- Escribir el código html en un archivo temporal para mostrar sólo en el momento.

Tu código debería hacer algo así:

```
def vg4():
    # Poligono de frecuencias
    plot_ax = datafi.groupby('Velocidad')['Cantidad'].sum().plot(kind='line',legend = 'Reverse')
    img = io.BytesIO()
    plot_ax.get_figure().savefig(img, format='png')
    img.seek(0)
    encoded_img = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue())
    htmlcode = '<img src="data:image/png;base64, {}">'.format(encoded_img.decode('utf-8'))
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False, suffix='.html') as f:
        url = 'file://' + f.name
        f.write(htmlcode)
    webbrowser.open(url)
```

Aquí un pequeño ejemplo completo:

```
import webbrowser
import pandas as pd
import io            # Para manejar la imagen como bytes
import base64        # Para codificar la imagen en base64
import tempfile      # Para crear un archivo html temporal

# Dummy data de ejemplo
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})

# Genera el plot y guarda el axis
plot_ax = df.groupby('Animal').mean().plot(kind='bar')

# Mantiene la imagen como bytes. Posteriormente se codifica a base64 para
# incrustarla en html. (Ver https://stackoverflow.com/a/49016797/3025562)
img = io.BytesIO()
plot_ax.get_figure().savefig(img, format='png')

img.seek(0)                                     # Mueve el puntero al inicio
encoded_img = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue())  # Codifica la imagen
# Incrusta la imagen en html
htmlcode = '<img src="data:image/png;base64, {}">'.format(encoded_img.decode('utf-8'))

# Guarda el codigo en un archivo temporal
# (Ver: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21437460/3025562)
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False, suffix='.html') as f:
    url = 'file://' + f.name
    f.write(htmlcode)

# Abre el archivo en webbrowser
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas el módulo `webrowser` para ello si solo quieres mostrar una gráfica en el navegador o en una red local, basta con que uses el backend WebAgg de Matplotlib (que es la biblioteca que pandas usa para las gráficas):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WebAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


vg1():
    # grafica absoluta
    datafi.groupby('Velocidad')['Cantidad'].sum().plot(kind='bar',legend='Reverse')
    plt.show()

vg1()
```

La ventaja es que no es una imagen estática, puedes de hecho usar animaciones:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WebAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
linea, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init_func():
    linea.set_data([], [])
    return linea,

def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    linea.set_data(x, y)
    return linea,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init_func,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si necesitas algo más complejo (múltiples figuras, tablas acompañando, etc), siempre puedes crear un pequeño servidor con tornado mismo.